# Query a SQL database using VBA

Tags: database, excel, vba, where-clause

I want to create a VBA program where it connects to the database you give it (hard coded). From here you are to program a cell to take the input for the WHERE clause in the query and then in a separate sheet it outputs the queried data. I do not want to filter this data, I need to query it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of database?  Excel has tools under `Data>>Get External Data` which can do this, so try recording a macro and see if you can modify it to do what you need.

Comment: Step #1 guard against SQL injection -see [here](http://xkcd.com/327/) Step #2 tell us what type of database you are trying to connect to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Microsoft Query. The basic steps are:

1 - Connect to the database using Data>From Other Sources>Microsoft Query

2 - Modify the resulting query by right-cliking the resulting table and choosing Table>External Data Properties and clicking the little icon in the upper-corner. Then choose the Definition tab:

[image]

3 - Right-click the table and choose Parameters. In that dialog you can set cells to hold the parameters for the Where clauses.

For more info on this see this [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-a-parameter-query-HP010216113.aspx) page and this [Daily Dose post](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-a-parameter-query-HP005199548.aspx).

Comment: So Doug, I did what you said there, and got that working. I ran a macro at the same time because I wanted to get VBA code so I can change it when I needed to. When I tried running the macro later I keep getting an error saying there is a run time error with the subscript out of range. When I click debug to show what is wrong it points me to this: With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from ProductId").ODBCConnection.

Comment: It means that your connection name isn't "Query from ProductId." I'd guess it might now be "Query from ProductId2". This kind of programming isn't trivial, so you'll have to figure out a bunch of things like this. Based on this little bit of information, I'd suggest you program it to use the same connection every time, which would mean not adding a new one. That sounds obvious when I say it, so sorry if it's not much help.